# SQL: Get next date value per row

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a table containing a date column.

```
ID  |      Date 
----|-----------
  1 | 2000-01-01
  2 | 2000-02-01
  3 | 2000-02-01
  4 | 2000-03-01
```

I need a select that returns for each row, the ID, the Date and the smallest date (of all dates in the table) that is larger than the current date.

```
ID  |      Date  |  Next date
----+------------+------------
  1 | 2000-01-01 | 2000-02-01
  2 | 2000-02-01 | 2000-03-01
  3 | 2000-02-01 | 2000-03-01
  4 | 2000-03-01 |     (NULL)
```

My first approach was

```
SELECT id, date, LEAD (date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date NULLS LAST) AS next_date
  FROM t
```

But this only works, if the values in column DATE are unique.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about a Join to a group by query where a.date > b.date and only use the first found record in b?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an analytic function with a [windowing clause](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Analytic-Functions.htm). `lead()` doesn't support a windowing clause, so you need use one that does like `min()` or `first_value()`:

```
FIRST_VALUE ("Date")
  OVER (ORDER BY "Date" RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

The default windowing clause is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, which would give all your rows the same value of `2000-01-01` and using a `ROWS` window would run into the same problem you're having with `lead()` with duplicate dates (ID 2 would still get `2000-02-01`; and ID 4 would get `2000-03-01` instead of null if you you used `ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW...` rather than `1 FOLLOWING`).

Demo using this range:

```
with t (ID, "Date") as (
  select 1, date '2000-01-01' from dual
  union all select 2, date '2000-02-01' from dual
  union all select 3, date '2000-02-01' from dual
  union all select 4, date '2000-03-01' from dual
)
select id, "Date", FIRST_VALUE ("Date") OVER (ORDER BY "Date"
  RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS next_date
FROM t;

        ID Date       NEXT_DATE 
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 2000-01-01 2000-02-01
         2 2000-02-01 2000-03-01
         3 2000-02-01 2000-03-01
         4 2000-03-01
```

Only rows where the date value is higher than the current row are considered. And this still only has to hit the table once.

(I've put `"Date"` in double-quotes because `date` is a reserved word; from your sample data it looks like a quoted identifier, but it isn't quoted in your query, so it's probably just got a more sensible name really...)

Comment: The best answer.

Comment: I like that. :-)

Comment: thats a very good answer,but in my case,your code is work successfully for one customer,when i execute my query for all customer its not worked .....he return me the end date same as start date.
can you say whats kinds problem is it?...i give my query below:

Comment: @S.M.FazleRabbi - you will need to ask a new question, showing your actual code, sample  data and current/expected results. I suspect you might just need to add `partition by customer` but can’t tell for sure without all the details, which are not suitable for a comment.

Comment: Ok.i will do it...but one request for you.i will very much glad to you if specially you answer my question.
Moreover how can i communicate with you ( chat or email or any others ) , or how do i notify you about my question?

Comment: here is my question link  as you say...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826305/getting-wrong-next-date-from-a-date-column-for-all-customer-oracle

Answer (score 6):

```
select * , (select min(t2.date) from table t2 where t2.date > t1.date)
from Table t1
```

Above code is in sql server

Comment: To make this valid in Oracle (ignoring the use of reserved words `table` and `date`), you have to prefix the `*` with the table alias if there are any other expressions, so `select t1.*, (select ...`

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question. ;-) (Just to show another option to people stumbling across this post)

Another solution would be using a subselect:

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.date,
       (SELECT MIN (t.date)
          FROM t t2
         WHERE t2.date > t.date)
          AS next_date
  FROM t;
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a CTE containing the *distinct* dates and their immediate lead values.  Then, join this CTE to your original table on the date to get the final result.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.date,
           LEAD(t.date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY t.date NULLS LAST) AS next_date
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM yourTable) t
)
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.date,
    t2.next_date
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.date = t2.date
```

Comment: That works. I need to check how it performs on larger tables. To be honest, I was hoping there's a less complex solution. :-) But thanks anyway.

Comment: This solution is actually relatively not complex.  The only trick is using `DISTINCT` to get around your duplicate dates.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, without "distinct":

```
select
  ted.id,
  ted.date_col,
  (select
    min(ted2.date_col)
  from
    test_date_v ted2
  where
    ted2.id != ted.id and
    ted2.date_col > ted.date_col) next_date_col
from
  test_date_v ted;
```

Comment: i see, you thought it throw on your own. Good job!