# Getting wrong next date from a date column for all customer Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

This is my NM_CUST_APPLIANCE_HISTORY table ( for custoner_id=96 ) .

```
Customer_id   | Last_effective_date | Present_quentity
--------------+---------------------+-----------------
    96        | 2009-12-20          | 10
    96        | 2014-11-18          | 12
    96        | 2015-11-26          | 14
```

I execute my query to get start_date and immediate date of next row as a end_date for a single customer ( customer_id=96 ) .

```
  SELECT NM.CUSTOMER_ID customer_id,
     NM.LATEST_EFFECTIVE_DATE start_date,
     NVL (
        CASE
           WHEN nm.LATEST_EFFECTIVE_DATE IS NULL
           THEN
              TO_DATE ('12/12/9999', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
           ELSE
              FIRST_VALUE (
                 nm.LATEST_EFFECTIVE_DATE)
              OVER (ORDER BY nm.LATEST_EFFECTIVE_DATE
                    RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
        END,
        TO_DATE ('12/12/9999', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
        end_date,
     NM.PRESENT_QUANTITY PRESENT_quantity
FROM nm_cust_appliance_history nm
WHERE NM.APPLIANCE_INFO_ID = 10484 
AND NM.CUSTOMER_ID = 96
ORDER BY customer_id, start_date;
```

And the result comes perfectly AS I WANT. like below :

```
Customer_id | START_DATE |  END_DATE  | PRESENT_QUANTITY
------------+------------+------------+-----------------
    96      | 2009-12-20 | 2014-11-18 |      10
    96      | 2014-11-18 | 2015-11-26 |      12
    96      | 2015-11-26 | 9999-12-12 |      14
```

But when i execute this query for all customer ( removing NM.CUSTOMER_ID = 96 from query ) it gives me same START_DATE and END_DATE and end_date comes added a day AS LIKE below ... I i also give you a snapshot of my output of query and marked out that customer result with **red color** box...

```
  SELECT NM.CUSTOMER_ID customer_id,
     NM.LATEST_EFFECTIVE_DATE start_date,
     NVL (
        CASE
           WHEN nm.LATEST_EFFECTIVE_DATE IS NULL
           THEN
              TO_DATE ('12/12/9999', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
           ELSE
              FIRST_VALUE (
                 nm.LATEST_EFFECTIVE_DATE)
              OVER (ORDER BY nm.LATEST_EFFECTIVE_DATE
                    RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
        END,
        TO_DATE ('12/12/9999', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
        end_date,
     NM.PRESENT_QUANTITY PRESENT_quantity
FROM nm_cust_appliance_history nm
WHERE NM.APPLIANCE_INFO_ID = 10484
--AND NM.CUSTOMER_ID = 96
ORDER BY customer_id, start_date;
```

### Result is:

```
Customer_id   | START_DATE  |  END_DATE  | Present_quentity
--------------+-------------+------------+-----------------
    74        | 2008-10-26  | 2008-10-27 |  5
 >  96        | 2009-12-20  | 2009-12-21 | 10
 >  96        | 2014-11-18  | 2014-11-19 | 12
 >  96        | 2015-11-26  | 2015-11-27 | 14
   100        | 2009-01-07  | 2009-01-09 |  7
```

## Image of query Result

[image: output of the query]

**I want the result for all customer like the result of single customer.
How can i solve my problem?
Help me any one**

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: ok ..i edit this

Comment: It would be helpful to include data for other customers, particularly those you show in the actual results, and whichever customer has the wrong dates you're currently seeing reported for customer 96.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your window clause is looking at `last_effective_dates` across all your data. You need to add a `partition by` clause to restrict it to the current customer:

```
  OVER (PARTITION BY nm.CUSTOMER_ID
        ORDER BY nm.LATEST_EFFECTIVE_DATE
        RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

So:

```
  SELECT NM.CUSTOMER_ID customer_id,
     NM.LATEST_EFFECTIVE_DATE start_date,
     NVL (
        CASE
           WHEN nm.LATEST_EFFECTIVE_DATE IS NULL
           THEN
              TO_DATE ('12/12/9999', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
           ELSE
              FIRST_VALUE (
                 nm.LATEST_EFFECTIVE_DATE)
              OVER (PARTITION BY nm.CUSTOMER_ID
                    ORDER BY nm.LATEST_EFFECTIVE_DATE
                    RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
        END,
        TO_DATE ('12/12/9999', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
        end_date,
     NM.PRESENT_QUANTITY PRESENT_quantity
FROM nm_cust_appliance_history nm
WHERE NM.APPLIANCE_INFO_ID = 10484
ORDER BY customer_id, start_date;
```

If you ever need to run it for more than one `appliance_info_id` then you'll need to add that to the `partition by clause` too.

Using a dummy extra record to kind of simulate what you're seeing, supplied via a CTE:

```
with nm_cust_appliance_history(appliance_info_id, customer_id, latest_effective_date, present_quantity) as (
  select 10484, 96, date '2009-12-20', 10 from dual
  union all select 10484, 96, date '2014-11-18', 12 from dual
  union all select 10484, 96, date '2015-11-26', 14 from dual
  union all select 10484, 42, date '2009-12-21', 15 from dual
)
```

your original query gets:

```
CUSTOMER_ID START_DATE END_DATE   PRESENT_QUANTITY
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------------
         42 2009-12-21 2014-11-18               15
         96 2009-12-20 2009-12-21               10
         96 2014-11-18 2015-11-26               12
         96 2015-11-26 9999-12-12               14
```

and the partition-by query above gets:

```
CUSTOMER_ID START_DATE END_DATE   PRESENT_QUANTITY
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------------
         42 2009-12-21 9999-12-12               15
         96 2009-12-20 2014-11-18               10
         96 2014-11-18 2015-11-26               12
         96 2015-11-26 9999-12-12               14
```

Comment: Thank you so much...your answer is worked as i want.....so glad to you sir.
you save me from a dangerous problem ........thanks ones again sir.....